# Updating table with POST from external program

Tags: post, insert, request

i have an external program which sends some data VIA POST to my server. I know the data is being sent because i echo the POST and its fine. but when i add an INSERT INTO query it doesnt work. here is my code: id = int (primary key), home,mob = double, the rest are varchar. Thanks in advanced.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('####','###','###','user');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Can't connect to SQL Server. Error Code %s\n",       mysqli_connect_error($mysqli));
exit;
}
$date   = $_POST['date'];
$desc   = $_POST['desc'];

mysqli->query("INSERT INTO user_info (id, home, mob, type, description, date) VALUES    (NULL,'','','',$desc,$date);");

mysql_real_escape_string($date),
mysql_real_escape_string($suburb));

$mysqli->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Is that your real code, or are you really not sanitizing data coming in to a web application?  What year is this?  There are still programmers out there that beg for SQL Injection attacks?  One of the first thing a client or employer should ask, is to write a few lines of code to insert a record into a database, and if it looks like that, immediately fire them as fast as they can.

Comment: i've never done sql or php before. that is my first attempt, and the server is not open to public its just a test server.

Comment: I know, but before anyone does any programming involving SQL, parameterizing and sanitizing the data should be understood before anyone is allowed to write a line of code.  internal intranet or not, it doesn't matter, get in the habit of sanitizing your data.  At least use the  mysql_real_escape_string function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks for the info, i just read about SQL injection.. didn't realize its so easy for someone to get access to a database. Thanks!, umm im not getting any errors. just nothing isn't being inserted. (i updated my code with escape_string_function)

Comment: actually this error just came up: 
      Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in      C:\wamp\www\user323.php on line 10

Comment: ok i just fixed that error realizing that $ was missing infront of mysqli->query... now there is no error, if i run it from my browser it comes up with error: undefined index, date and suburb... but thats because im not sending any post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your error message, you are missing the "$" on your $mysqli->query, corrected code should be:

for additional issues, try to get the SQL that is being sent to the database, and run it on a local query to see if there are SQL errors that you are missing.

```
<?php
$date   = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['date'] );
$desc   = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['desc'] );

$query =<<<SQLQUERY
     INSERT INTO user_info 
              (home, mob, type, description, date) 
        VALUES    
              ('',   '',  '',   $desc,       $date)
SQLQUERY;

// Can you print out or get the value for $query?

$mysqli->query($query);

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: yeah i corrected that, i posted in the comment above but it got hidden. Now no errors but nothing is being inserted into my table.

Comment: I'm assuming the id on the user_info is an auto increment.  If it is, you shouldn't need to pass it in the query at all. If it isn't and it's the primary key, that might be an issue as well.

Comment: yep its auto increment, ok ill give it a go.

Comment: instead of going through my program, is there anyway to do it through the browser directly. e.g host/user.php?date=20110710&desc=hithere
so that way i can test directly and not through my app.